# Report Builder 3.0: How do I specify the dataset for this textbox?

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

I made a simple query to return 1 field. One of the fields is the user's input.

Item (input)
Description (return value)

I now want to use the returned value in a simple textbox on the report, but it's giving me a scope error. Makes sense, but how do I tell the textbox which dataset to look in (there are multiple datasets)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right mouse click on the text box you can create a placeholder. 
You can then specify the value of this placeholder to be the required value from the dataset.